# NPM looking in wrong place for React module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-start

Firstly I am not 100% certain my Question title is accurate being that I am very new to NPM/Node/React/VSCode.

I am following a tutorial and am at a step where I created a React app using the command:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Net Core> npx create-react-app client-app --use-npm --typescript
```

Which appears to have successfully installed the app in:
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Net Core . "Net Core" being the name of the project.

However when I try to run the following in the terminal I get an error that the react-scripts.js module cannot be found:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Net Core\client-app> npm start
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'

The fact that it is looking for 'react-scripts" in the Programming folder makes no sense to me.

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.38

NPM version 6.11.3

Node.js version 10.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `npm install` in the directory before you run `npm start`.

Comment: Didn't make a difference, same behavior.